# Strange search result with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this phrase stored under the field address: "Koželužská 290, 33805 Mýto"

I'm trying to search for part of this string like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Koželužská 290, 33*",
            "fields": ["address"],
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the result of one record which is correct.

But if I try to search for part of the string like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Koželužská 290,*",
            "fields": ["address"],
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any result.

Does anyone know why or what is wrong?

Comment: Please also share the mapping for the field `address`, especially the type. Please note that wildcards are not common in Elastic. Per default, the text will be tokenized and searched independently. The more tokens are contained (e.g. "Koželužská", "290"), the higher is the result score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the config:  "analyze_wildcard": true,

> By setting analyze_wildcard to true, queries that end with a * will be
> analyzed and a boolean query will be built out of the different
> tokens, by ensuring exact matches on the first N-1 tokens, and prefix
> match on the last token.

```
{
  "profile": false,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "Koželužská 290,*",
      "fields": [
        "address"
      ],
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```